# Opensso support for Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 7+

Tags: openam, opensso

We are currently using OpenSSO in some of our legacy applications and for few applications we want to use either web/jee policy agents with opensso.

**Since OpenSSO is a dead project do we have any support for Apache 2.4 or Tomcat 7 or 8?**

I know we can migrate to OpenAM, but currently we are not allowed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there are supported OpenSSO agents for those containers. You should really try to switch to OpenAM, the agents for AM does support Apache 2.4, and Tomcat 7/8.

Alternatively you can attempt to use the AM agents with your OpenSSO, but such setups were certainly never tested by ForgeRock.